# Why did my available amount of flags per day increase?

Tags: discussion, flags

I started to use my flag privilege and initially had only 10 flags per day.

But after couple of days my available amount of flags increased by 1. And now I see:

> 11 flags remaining

What is the reason? Will it increase again if I use my privilege more frequently?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of flags you can cast per day starts off at 10, but you can get more:

- one extra flag per 2k rep increase
- one extra flag for every 10 helpful flags (minus unhelpful ones)

This is capped at 100 flags per day.

Reference: [On the recent changes to flagging and limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits/185890#185890)